# Analogies: a special kind of relationship between vocabulary words

Tags: vocabulary, analogy

I have seen the following in the book "*Vocabulary for High-School Students*".

The book says the fact that the following has some relationship between each other. Nonetheless, I failed to get it.

- exemption: privilege
- reading: skill
- shiftless: objective
- callous: sympathy

Comment: Please provide us with what explanation the book gives in support of their claim about it.

Comment: Something similar in [*Skyfall* (2012)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1074638/quotes?item=qt1699698): Dr. Hall: "I'd like to start with some simple word associations. Just tell me the first word that pops into your head. For example, I say, *Day* and you might say..." Bond: "Wasted." Dr. Hall: "All right." Then they start a series of quick exchanges: Gun - Shot. Agent - Provocateur. Woman - Provocatrix. Heart - Target. Bird - Sky. M - Bitch. (M sighs) Sunlight - Swim. Moon - Dance. Murder - Employment. Country - England. Skyfall - (silence). Skyfall - (after a few seconds) Done.

Comment: Considering the title of the book is ungrammatical (unless it's meant only for a few specific students), I wouldn't waste time taking advice from it.

Comment: Photon, what do you think the title should be?....or did OP already edit it?

Comment: Did the book say there was _some_ telationship, or the _same_ relationship, or that only some of them (not all of them) had a relationship?  This looks like some questions in the SAT, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAT wherein they ask you to identify which pair does NOT have a relationship.

Comment: I don't see the sense of such plays. A lot of exercises are totally beside the point.

Comment: http://www.mhhe.com/socscience/english/spears/stu3/studisk/verbal_analogies/va_intro.htm lists common kinds of analogies.

Answer (score 1):

1. Exemption: Privilege

If someone is exempted from paying for admission to a concert that could be considered a privilege.

2. Reading: skill

Reading is considered to be a skill as it has to be learned. No one is born with this ability.

3. Shiftless: objective

Someone who is shiftless has no plan in life and is usually considered lazy.

Someone who has an objective in life (or a plan) could be considered to be a person possessing characteristics that that are the OPPOSITE of a shiftless person.

4. Callous: sympathy

If someone commits a callous act they are showing themselves to possess a characteristic that is the OPPOSITE of sympathy.

So, numbers 1 and 2 have CLOSE relationships in meaning and numbers 3 and 4 have OPPOSITE relationships in meaning.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: However, number three is different from all others; you can take "objective" as a _noun_ as you did. Then the words on either side of the colon are not the same _part of speech_. And if you take "objective" as an adjective, its opposite would be "subjective", not "shiftless".  The fourth has the same part-of-speech mismatch, but  if you read "sympathy" as "_sympathetic_" it's an antonym of "callous.  So if the question is: which pair is NOT a good analogy, I'd pick the third one.